# Returning a set for all individual letters, vs a set for each word

Tags: python

I don't understand why I am receiving a set for each individual letter when I have the code below; however, when I simply remove the '''if word in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':''' then I receive a set for each phrase. However, I need something that will remove anything that isn't a space (i.e. / [ ] - etc., from the larger passage, so the abcd was the best I could think of for this).

Two follow-up questions:

1. It seems that if I use return vs print, I receive two different answers (return only returns the last set; where print returns all sets).
2. Rather than having it be 5 individual sets, how would I put this into a list of 5 sets?

```
def make_itemsets(words):
    words = str(words)
    words.lower().split()
    for word in words:
        newset = set()
        if word in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
            newset.update(word)
        
            print(newset)

words = ['sed', 'ut', 'perspiciatis', 'unde', 'omnis']    
make_itemsets(words)
```

This returns the five lists (but doesn't remove all excess and won't remove non-characters from the larger passage):

```
def make_itemsets(words):
    words = str(words)
    words.lower().split()
    for word in words:
        newset = set()
        newset.update(word)
        
        print(newset)
```

This would be expected output:

```
[{'d', 'e', 's'},
 {'t', 'u'},
 {'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'p', 'r', 's', 't'},
 {'d', 'e', 'n', 'u'},
 {'i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 's'}]
```

Comment: `words.lower().split()` does not do what you think it does. It is not in place

Comment: hmmm...if if print "words" after it, it appears to be changing it to lower and adding a space, no?

Comment: What is your expected output for input `['sed', 'ut', 'perspiciatis', 'unde', 'omnis']` ?

Comment: words.lower().split() is done but result is not affected. do something like words = words.lower().split() if needed.

Comment: Could you specify you expected output ? This would be easier to understand what you want to obtain at the end.

Comment: Just added expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your expected output like this:

```
print ( [set(w) for w in words] )
```

Output is:

```
[{'d', 's', 'e'}, {'u', 't'}, {'p', 'e', 'i', 'a', 'c', 'r', 's', 't'}, {'d', 'u', 'e', 'n'}, {'m', 'i', 'o', 's', 'n'}]
```

Note that sets have no order.

If you want words which are alphabetic characters only, you can do this:

```
print ( [set(w) for w in words if w.isalpha()] )
```

Comment: Or even `list(map(set, words))`

Answer (score 0):

Match all clusters containing only letters:

`for word in re.compile('[a-z]+').findall('sed ut perspfkdls'):`

If you want to keep create a list for aggragated results:

```
result = []
...
   result.append({c for c in word})
...
return result
```

Edit: I updated my answer after reading the clarification.

```
def make_itemsets(words):
    matcher = re.compile('[a-z]+')
    words = str(words).lower()
    words = matcher.findall(words)
    return [{c for c in w} for w in words]
```

Edit 2: I already gave almost a complete implementation, so I connected the dots.